# Laravel 5.1 Auth not working on server while on local environment its doing right job

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-authorization

Laravel 5.1.35 authentication is not working after deploying on server. While on local environment its working fine.

As default successful login redirects to '/home'  and in /home rout handler Auth::check() returns false.

```
Route::get( '/home', function () {
  var_dump(Auth::user()); 
} );
```

Above code prints bool(false);

routs code:

```
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::get( '/home', function () {
  var_dump(Auth::user());
} );

Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('/login/{param}', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::get('/signup', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('/auth/stepOne', 'Auth\AuthController@stepOne');
Route::post('/auth/stepTwo', 'Auth\AuthController@stepTwo');
Route::post('/auth/stepTwoBrand', 'Auth\AuthController@stepTwoBrand');
Route::post('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem was a blank line before php starting tag.

I used following core php function to redirect instead of returning a view file from controller or instead of using laravel riderect.

```
header('Location: /');
```

It printed actual file which had blank line. Removing this line fixed my problem.

There were thousands of files in my code base. My assumption was that I have tried different scripts to find such blank lines at start of any file and there was no such file as per those scripts results. I assumed there is is no blank line in any of my files. But header('Location: /') proved that my assumption was not wrong and I was working on wrong lines.